# Need to check the value of a field, then display another using a Cleditor form

Tags: javascript, php, html, cleditor

I apologize in advance, I am trying to do something more advanced than what I was hired for, so my key words, understanding and syntax's will likely be very wrong.

I am setting up a cloud based DBMS that has a custom document creator. I believe they are using cleditor. I need a way on the form to do some sort of If statement. To populate a value from the DB, the tags used are like {Equipment:Manufacturer} and then whatever the value of the field is shows in the form.  I need a way to check the value of one of these tags, and then display another field based on that choice.

If I need to clarify anything or have not stated what I a looking for clearly, please let me know so I can learn.

I have tried adding  but those get stripped out. I tried something like {Equipment:Manufacturer}==="Manuf" and several variations on that.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you've tried please? Quite a bit of context missing imo.

Comment: The form was created by converting a pdf into html and then uploading the source code into the form creator. This was how the recommended it to be done to me.  I don't appear to be able to add a < s c r i p t> into the document as it just strips out whatever is in those script tags. 

I have tried variations on just having  if{Equipment:Type =="MyValue"} (console.log {Equipment:Manufacturer})
I have tried changing where the IF is in relation to ( ) and the == in or out of { } and also tried ===.

Comment: This is an example of a snippet of the form that pull in the info to it correctly.
"   <td style="height: 20px; width: 326px;" colspan="8" align="left" valign="bottom"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial;"> {CustomerContact:Email1}</span></td>   "

Comment: This is an example of where I need the value checked. Apparently the {Job:EquipmentBegin} is a quirk of the system needed to point it to the right table (object?)
" <tr style="height: 18px;">
   <td style="height: 18px; width: 452px;" colspan="9" align="left" valign="bottom" height="18"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial;"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial;">METER MANUFACTURER:{Job:EquipmentBegin} {Equipment:Manufacturer}<br /></span></span></td>  "

Comment: The issue I face is the way their system works, is it just pulls stuff in, in an order listed. No way to point it to the right piece of equipment. So it will give me a manufacturer, but it's only correct if it happens to be the first item in the list (table).